# regex only letter and - allowed

Tags: regex, input

I want to make a pattern for input.

I have this [A-Za-z]|-, but if I type `dsadsa$` this, the special characters still allowed and I need only
`big and small letters`, and `-` .

Comment: What programming language/ regex engine are you using?

Comment: Use `^[A-Za-z-]+$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can escape - character:

```
[A-Za-z\-]
```

Comment: Same for Unicode:[\pL\-]

Answer (score 0):

Your expression should be like following:

- ([A-Za-z\-]+)
- ([\w-]+)